# QVector to Complex

Tags: c++, qt, format, complex-numbers

I am trying to assign part of a `QVector` double array to complex double array in Qt.

Running the following code, I have the problem that `std::cout << y.at(i) << std::endl;` correctly prints a 16-bit integer value but `std::cout << y1[i] << std::endl;` prints zeros: (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) ...

I would like the result (y[0],0) (y[1],0) (y[2],0)...

Please can someone advise what is wrong?

```
QVector<double> x(100), y(100);  // Original QVector

std::complex<double> y1[100];
int i=0;

while(i<101)
{  
   // get y values from somewhere else (quint8 data8)

   y[i] = (256.0*data8[2*i]) + 1.0*data8[2*i+1];
   std::cout << y.at(i) << std::endl;

   y1[i] = (y.at(i),0.0);
   std::cout << y1[i] << std::endl;

   i++;
}
```

Comment: Comma operator.

Comment: C++ is not Python and an exceptional bad fit for programming based on trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this expression:

```
(y.at(i), 0.0)
```

In C++ parentheses are just a grouping technique, which is used for operator precedence designation. For example, if you execute `2*2+2`, you'll get six. But if you want to get eight, you need parentheses: `2*(2+2)`. So you assignment line is equivalent to:

```
y1[i] = y.at(i), 0.0;
```

Why does it compile and what does it mean? It compiles because a [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) is used. In C++, comma is a binary operator with a very simple action: it computes it's left-hand argument, throws the result away, then computes it's right-hand argument and returns the result. So in your case it discarded `y.at(i)` and returned zero, which was successfully assigned to `y1[i]`. The shortest way to do what you want in modern C++ is to use initializer lists:

```
y1[i] = {y.at(i),0.0};
```

If you have an ancient compiler, it's just a bit more verbose:

```
y1[i] = std::complex<double>(y.at(i), 0.0);
```

Comment: OK, silly mistake.  Thank you for the thorough explanation as I was not familiar with that syntax, or the comma operator.  I hope this is useful for other Qt / C++ newcomers to learn from.

Comment: @MichaelT If the answer is helpful for you, consider accepting it